# AFNetworking causes crash at response

Tags: ios, afnetworking

**Crash Scenario**
I am using AFNetworking for **GET** and **POST** requests and I am calling **GET** and **POST** methods on **MAIN QUEUE** and when the response comes,I update the UI.Now,before the response comes from API I am pushing onto another **ViewController**,and that's when the crash occurs.
**The message says:**bad_access
**Possible Solution**
Should I be calling that method on some background queue so that I Can update that on **MAIN QUEUE**.Is it correct? 
**Here is the code:**

```
    -(void)getDataFromUrl:(NSString *)url withRequestName:(NSString *)requestName withMessege:(NSMutableDictionary *)message
    {

     Reachability* googleReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    if(googleReach.currentReachabilityStatus!=0)
    {

        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

        [manager GET:url parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"output :%@", responseObject);

        arrayParsedJson =  (NSMutableArray * )responseObject;
        [self.delegate dataReceivedFromService:arrayParsedJson withRequestName:requestName];

        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        [self.delegate dataReceivedErrorService:error withRequestName:requestName withMsg:error.description];
    }];

    }
    else
    {
    //[TSMessage showNotificationInViewController:views title:Title_Alert subtitle:Service_Alert type:TSMessageNotificationTypeError];
    }
}
```

So when I get response in the success block,I call my delegate methods you can see.But if I have navigated to some other viewController before the response comes in block, it crashes.

Comment: show the crash report

Comment: Will you please add you code here

Comment: ok give me 10 mins...

Comment: use completion blocks instead of delegates

Comment: @raki Why so?Could you please explain?

Comment: where you are setting that delegate?

Comment: In the view controller from where I am calling this method.This method above is in my 'ServiceCaller' class and I am calling it from ,say ViewController A...